# How do I generate a report of where multiple specific fields are being used in an org?

Tags: reporting, fields

I want to generate a report of where multiple specific fields are being used in my org. I know that Salesforce has a 'Where is this used?' button for each field which shows where that particular field is being used. Is there a way to generate a report for this instead of visiting each field manually?

Comment: There is no standard reporting for this, you'll need to use a 3rd party metadata search tool on AppExchange.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCheng. I was able to find a 3rd party tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned there is no standard process,  You can use '[Field Trip](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321289&type=1&mode=1)' which helps analyze and report on which fields from which object in your organization are used consistently and which fields are left unused. The Field Trip report provides the percentage of utilization of each field. This helps to get field utilization report results and to conclude if we can delete the fields which are not in use.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried another app called 'FieldPro' and it helped with this.